# Able to generate token for salesforce using postman but same i tried using logic app but getting grant_type error

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, salesforce, azure-logic-apps

I want to generate salesforce token using url 
`https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token` and parameters, I tried with postman it is wokring fine.

But when I use same parameters in logic app HTTP it is throwing error `invalid grant type`

what could be wrong while in logic app anyone ?
tried like this too-
[image]

[image]

[image]

in postman all going good -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postman your content type is raw, in azure it's urlencoded
experiment with it. when you go raw, your username's "@" sign is sent as "@" or manually encoded to %40?
What if you delete the urlencoded header from Azure app?

Comment: I even tried it with query parameter updated question.

Comment: No, I don't expect query params to work. Query params would go to URL, right? (like GET), this has to go to body (like POST). Without the "urlencoded" header and with manually encoded "%40" still doesn't work? And it's still "invalid grant type", not "invalid grant, authentication failure"?

Comment: let me try it again it seems my server is down :( will keep you posted  , even i tries like this question updated

Comment: nope same error :(
{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "grant type not supported"
}

Comment: what if my username is - my@123 and password is also like - pass@123 ?? how to pass values?

Comment: i achieved using salesforce connector